# Why is my code working as intended without DataContext and breaking when I add a DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I'm creating a UserControl with two buttons (Hello and World) that add 'Hello' and 'World' to a string which is displayed in a TextBox.

The code is currently working as intended but only when I don't set a DataContext for the UserControl. Once I do set the DataContext, the buttons no longer work.

```
<UserControl x:Class="QualityAssuranceAssistance.Views.HomeView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QualityAssuranceAssistance.ViewModels;assembly=QualityAssuranceAssistance.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="420" Width="660">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:HomeViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding HelloButton}"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommandLive}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="208,243,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="{Binding WorldButton}"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommandTest}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="377,243,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="75"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding StringViewModels, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Height="56" 
                 Width="640"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I think the problem has something to do with the constructor. When I set the DataContext, initially Visual Studio complained that my ViewModel didn't have any accessible constructors. After some googling, I found someone who suggested adding another constructor without parameters. I'm guessing that for some reason that constructor is now being used to create an instance of the ViewModel, which is why the commands in my other constructor are not created.

```cs
        public HomeViewModel(List<IPageViewModel> viewModels)
        {
            ClickCommandLive = new RelayCommand(AddLivePages, CanExecute);
            ClickCommandTest = new RelayCommand(AddTestPages, CanExecute);
            _viewModels = viewModels;

        }

        public HomeViewModel() { }
```

I expected my code only to work when the DataContext is set and to not work when it's not set. Instead without DataContext it seems to work as I'd expect with DataContext set. I'm still very new to WPF (and XAML) and C#, so I'm almost certainly missing something very obvious but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: Your button binds to `ClickCommandLive`. In your parameterless constructor, you leave that property null. Obviously a null command isn't going to do anything. You aren't initializing the viewmodel any more. Do you understand what constructors mean in C#?

Comment: Right, I mean preferably I wouldn't have to use the parameterless constructor at all, but then I can't set the DataContext. When I don't set the DataContext explicitly like this, the code actually seems to work fine - which is confusing to me. I suppose I phrased my question a bit awkwardly cause I figured the parameterless constructor was the problem, but I don't quite get why I need it and when it's called.

Comment: You need to read up about how class instances are constructed in C#. It's not mysterious voodoo, it's very clear and straightforward. You create a class instance by calling one single solitary constructor and **only** that one single constructor and **no other constructor at all**. You class has two constructors. One **OR** the other is called. That constructor initializes the class (or not, in your case). `<local:HomeViewModel/>` calls the parameterless constructor. Ask yourself where in this code you initialize any class members: `public HomeViewModel() { }
`

Comment: You can write a constructor which **explicitly** invokes the other constructor: `public HomeViewModel() : this(null) { }` -- but then `_viewModels` will be null, which may turn out to be a problem.

Comment: As a rule, I'm not a fan of UserControls creating their own viewmodels, because of initialization. But it's important for you to understand exactly what went wrong in this code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Stupid of me to think that adding that constructor would help anything. So based on what you're saying, one thing I hadn't realised yet is that setting the datacontext initializes the viewmodel, correct? I've been working based on another project and after your comments I realised that I didn't quite get how it was working, but it was instantiating the viewmodels from the main window viewmodel and then using datatemplates main window view to make sure that the different UserControls were drawn correctly. This is also why I don't need to set the DataContext.

Comment: *"setting the datacontext initializes the viewmodel"* -- Absolutely not. You are **creating the instance of the viewmodel in your XAML**. Creating the viewmodel via a constructor is what initializes it. When you create a viewmodel instance in XAML like that, it always uses the parameterless constructor, thus requiring you to have one. Are you also calling the other constructor somewhere else -- that is to say, creating a different instance? Or did you think that when you instantiate the class with one constructor, all the other constructors would execute as well?

Comment: Right, but I create it in my XAML by setting the datacontext, no? If I don't set the datacontext, the constructor won't be called to initialise the viewmodel. And yeah the other viewmodel called the other constructor, that's what I was trying to explain (but probably didn't do a very good job of) with my other comment.

Comment: The XAML snippet you provided first creates a new instance via the parameterless constructor, and then assigns the new instance to the DataContext property. I'm being very finicky about language here (annoyingly so, I'm sure) because I still don't understand why you wrote a parameterless constructor that doesn't initialize anything. That suggests to me that you're likely to be working from an incorrect assumption somewhere along the line. So I don't want any assumptions slipping back in.

Comment: *The XAML snippet you provided first creates a new instance via the parameterless constructor* - is there a specific line that does that? I'm not quite understanding where that is happening. And it's not annoying in the slightest, it's helping me see the things I clearly don't/didn't understand. The parameterless constructor was from some answer I found elsewhere on stackoverflow as a solution to a problem I was having. Which I tried out without (clearly) thinking about what I was doing. I realise that having two constructors and thinking that they will somehow both work together is silly.

Comment: This XAML snippet creates a new instance of the Button class, via Button's parameterless constructor: `<Button Content="Foo" />`. This XAML snippet creates a new instance of `HomeViewModel` via `HomeViewModel`'s parameterless constructor: `<local:HomeViewModel/>`.

Comment: There are two ways to assign a value to a property of a XAML element: `<Button Content="Foo" />`, or `<Button><Button.Content>Foo</Button.Content></Button>`. The latter is what's happening with `<UserControl.DataContext><local:HomeViewModel/></UserControl.DataContext>`. There's no way to create an instance of your viewmodel via the XML-attribute syntax `<UserControl DataContext="...">` (When you see something in curly braces in an attribute value like `<Label Content="{StaticResource SomeResKey}" />`, it is constructing a `StaticResource` instance -- but IMO that's an unhelpful tangent ATM)